# EventSource "event" parameter not set in required PHP file on server

Tags: javascript, php, eventsource

I wasn't sure how to best explain this issue.

I have a Javascript EventSource object with some custom event handlers such as this:

```
var source = new EventSource('updates.php');
source.addEventListener('add', addHandler, false);
source.addEventListener('remove', removeHandler, false);
```

In updates.php, I can define custom events using the "event:" parameter of the update stream as follows, to trigger the appropriate handler.

```
echo "event: add" . PHP_EOL;
echo "data: " . $message . PHP_EOL;
```

This works fine in updates.php

updates.php includes updates2.php via require_once. This also works in updates2.php, and calls the right handler back in my Javascript.

updates2.php includes updates3.php via require_once. This DOES NOT work in updates3.php - all events default to the "message" type and do not trigger custom handlers.

Comment: Did content type is set to text/event-stream , header('Content-Type: text/event-stream'); ?

Comment: Can you include all `php` files at Question? Are any errors logged at server or `EventSource` `error` handler?

Comment: @GaneshK I've set the content type, it works correctly everywhere but the one included php file.

No errors in the onerror handlers - it logs it to onmessage as a default message instead of a custom typed event

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the workaround defined in a few other places.

Instead of attempting to custom-define the event: parameter, I instead used a JSON object as the data: parameter and can add any custom fields I like within that.